# Why can't I return true? am I making a mistake in the database query part?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, mysql-workbench

I have tried all kinds of combinations since morning but I can't `return` any `true` value. The information I entered is completely correct.

Help me pls why can't I `return true`? am I making a mistake in the database query part?

```java
 
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author seyme
 */
public class para_ekle extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private boolean ahmet;

    /**
     * Creates new form para_ekle
     */
    public para_ekle() {
        initComponents();
    }
    static boolean ekle = false;
public void kontrol() throws SQLException{
       
        Connection connect = null;
        dbbaglanti db = new dbbaglanti();
        connect = db.getConnection();
        Statement oku = ( Statement) connect.createStatement();
         
          String cekilenid = idtext4.getText();
          int cevrilenid = Integer.parseInt(cekilenid);
          String sifrebilgisi = sifretext4.getText();
          String tutarbilgisi = idtext4.getText();
          int cevrilentutar = Integer.parseInt(tutarbilgisi);
        try {
          
  
          
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bilgilerde Bir Hata Bulunuyor!");        
        }
         ResultSet rs;
        rs = oku.executeQuery("SELECT count(id) as \"giris\" FROM dbkullanici.kullanicilar WHERE id ="+ cevrilenid +" && sifre = '"+sifrebilgisi+"'" +";");
         while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("giris");
           if(id == 1){ boolean ahmet = ekle == true; } else if (id == 0 ){boolean ahmet = ekle == false;}
         }
         if(ahmet == true){
         erortext.setText("verilerdogru");
         }else if(ahmet == false){
             
         erortext.setText("Bilgileriniz Veritabanımızda ki veriler ile eşleşmedi");
         
     
        }
         
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        idtext4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        sifretext4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tutartext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        erortext = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI Black", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("ISSEY FİNANS SİSTEMİ");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ink Free", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("ISSEY ile paralarınız daha değerli");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 428, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(128, 128, 128))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Hesap Şifreniz: ");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Hesap İd Numaranızı Yazınız: ");

        idtext4.setText("jTextField1");

        sifretext4.setText("jTextField2");

        jLabel7.setText("İd Numaranızı Bilmiyorsanız Kullanıcı listeleme panelinden görüntüleyebilirsiniz.");

        jButton1.setText("Ana Menü'ye Dön");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Eklemek İstediğiniz Tutar");

        tutartext.setText("jTextField1");

        erortext.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));

        jButton2.setText("Para Ekle");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        jLabel4.setText(" Para Eklemi işlemi için tüm bilgileri büyük küçük harf ve boşluk dahil doğru girmelisiniz.");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(erortext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 390, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(55, 55, 55))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 188, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 142, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                                    .addComponent(idtext4)
                                                    .addComponent(sifretext4)
                                                    .addComponent(tutartext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)))
                                .addGap(61, 61, 61))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 408, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(23, 23, 23))))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(idtext4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(sifretext4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(tutartext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(erortext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            kontrol();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(para_ekle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(para_ekle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(para_ekle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(para_ekle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(para_ekle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new para_ekle().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel erortext;
    private javax.swing.JTextField idtext4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField sifretext4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tutartext;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  That code is incomplete.

Comment: @StephenC I apologize, this is my first time posting on this site. is the new version enough?

Comment: For one thing, if you want to return a boolean, you should declare the method as returning `boolean` (all your methods return `void`, like `void kontrol()`) .  Also, do you realise that in your statement `if(id == 1){ boolean ahmet =`, you are declaring a new variable `ahmet`, so you are not affecting the class’ instance variable of the same name.

Comment: @racraman I don't know how to thank you or send you a gift. I lost 3.5 hours because of my stupidity.

Comment: Glad to help - seeing what we think we wrote instead of what we actually wrote is something we have all done !